# uvc_camera applies max values for brightness and contrast

Tags: ros, ros-groovy, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using `uvc_camera` to capture image streams in ROS before. It has changed its behavior recently and I can't figure out why or how to revert it.

When opening my capture device, `rosrun uvc_camera camera_node _device:=/dev/video1`, it will print out its parameters as usual. The parameters of interest are:

```
  int (Brightness, 0, id = 980900): -16 to 16 (1)
  int (Contrast, 0, id = 980901): 1 to 32 (1)
```

Looking at the stream with `rosrun image_view image_view image:=image_raw` shows an image that is by far too white, contradicting the zero values for both brightness and contrast. Looking at the camera device, after turning of the `uvc_camera` node, with `guvcview` shows that the Brightness and Contrast parameters are set to their max values, 16 and 32, respectively.

Using the same application, `guvcview`, I can revert the parameters to their default values. However, when turning on the `uvc_camera` node again, the image will again be too white.

As I mentioned, I have used `uvc_camera` before on the same and other webcams. The faulty behavior does not change when changing webcams.

I am stuck here, any suggestions on how to get a proper image stream are more than welcome.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60560/uvc_camera-applies-max-values-for-brightness-and-contrast/) by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 386 on 2013-04-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My current workaround is to use `gscam`: "http://ros.org/wiki/gscam". It does not provide an easy configuration of device and settings, but it at least doesn't apply incorrect settings.

---

Originally posted by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) with karma: 386 on 2013-04-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was trying uvc_camera with my cheap webcam, but the images came out all white. After that, until plugged out and in again the webcam was outputting white even with usb_cam. You mentioned that it might be messing with parameters. And indeed, uvc_cam.cpp has like 15 hardcoded calls to set various parameters my webcam has probably never heard about. So, I commented out all those calls and it worked!

---

Originally posted by [Girts L](https://answers.ros.org/users/3081/girts-l/) with karma: 196 on 2014-03-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-03-09**:
Nice, good that you share. I'm currently not working with webcam anymore, but I'll keep this in mind.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-25**:
Hi, I'm experiencing the same effects using uvc_camera on Hydro. Looking for uvc_cam.cpp I can't find it. Any suggestions ?

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-06-25**:
Take a look here: https://github.com/ktossell/camera_umd/tree/master/uvc_camera.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-25**:
Ok, thank you. I found the hardcoded settings, but how should I proceed from here ?

**Comment by [RafBerkvens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4316/rafberkvens/) on 2014-06-25**:
Well, what I did was stop using uvc_camera and start using gscam.

**Comment by [hvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3729/hvn/) on 2014-06-25**:
Ok, I used gscam before and that didn't work out for me. So I started using uvc_camera although I'm using Hydro not Groovy

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2014-06-26**:
I've removed the hardcoded values. Now it'll just use whatever defaults the camera provides. If your camera is USB Video Class compliant (most webcams are), you should try http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera , which is my replacement for uvc_camera.